How to make a multi-value slider in Godot?
In Godot 4.3, I need a multi-value range slider, that does not accept user interaction.
I need to show a range of values (0 - 100) and also a range of accepted values
(40-60, for example). And finally, I need to show what value we currently have (51).
Here is a mock-up of what I want to achieve, made with image editing software:

I think the best way is to modify an Hslider. Here is a basic one by default out of Godot:

However, I would need to add another grabber at the beginning and modify the white highlight bar to follow that grabber. Do you have any ideas on how to do that with code?

If such a slider "does not accept user interaction", it means the grabbers cannot be, in fact, grabbed and serve only visual purposes, correct?

Yeah I wrote that because I want to focus on the main function of the multi slider, not user input. But yeah grabber is a bad name I used. Just call them markers :D

The following solution builds on top of HScrollBar and uses custom code for drawing.
The script below @exports two variables to update the HScrollBar properties via setter functions. The drawing function computes the position of the boundary values and current value markers in local space; additionally, it draws some knobs and a balloon, but you can replace the second part with your custom drawing logic.
How to use:

Create a HScrollBar Node.
Attach a script, and paste the code below.
From the Inspector, set Control > Mouse > Filter to "Ignore".

extends HScrollBar

@export var accepted_range: Vector2: set = set_accepted_range
@export var current_value: float: set = set_current_value


func set_accepted_range(new_range: Vector2) -> void:
    accepted_range = new_range.clampf(min_value, max_value)
    value = accepted_range.x
    page = accepted_range.y - accepted_range.x
    set_current_value(current_value)


func set_current_value(new_value: float) -> void:
    current_value = clampf(new_value, accepted_range.x, accepted_range.y)
    queue_redraw()


func _draw() -> void:
    var marker_min_pos: Vector2 = position + Vector2(accepted_range.x / max_value * size.x, 4.0)
    var marker_max_pos: Vector2 = position + Vector2(accepted_range.y / max_value * size.x, 4.0)
    var marker_curr_pos: Vector2 = position + Vector2(current_value / max_value * size.x, 4.0)

    const offset := Vector2(-7.0, 4.5)
    draw_circle(marker_min_pos, 10.0, Color.WHITE)
    draw_string(ThemeDB.fallback_font, marker_min_pos + offset, str(accepted_range.x), 0, -1, 12, Color.BLACK)
    draw_circle(marker_max_pos, 10.0, Color.WHITE)
    draw_string(ThemeDB.fallback_font, marker_max_pos + offset, str(accepted_range.y), 0, -1, 12, Color.BLACK)
    const marker_size := Vector2(30.0, 20.0)
    const marker_offset := Vector2(0.0, -18.0)
    draw_rect(Rect2(marker_curr_pos - marker_size/2.0 + marker_offset, marker_size), Color.WHITE)
    draw_circle(marker_curr_pos + Vector2.UP * 8.0, 4.0, Color.WHITE)
    draw_string(ThemeDB.fallback_font, marker_curr_pos + offset + Vector2.UP * (-marker_offset.y), str(current_value), 0, -1, 12, Color.BLACK)

Preview based on your mock-up:


Just a beautiful solution. Well done and thank you.
